# Do I need to stay a minimum number of days in the Schengen country my visa is for?

Tags: visas, schengen

I am planning to visit four Schengen countries, and am planning to apply for a visa through Germany.

Is there any minimum number of days I should be staying in the country through which I apply?

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to be clear as possible - include your county of citizenship, which countries and so on, and make your title more specific to your situation - we have a few experts on here for Schengen, but they might miss it in its present form.  Also see the [help] on how best to word a question on here. Thanks!

Comment: @Gauri I've suggested an edit to clear the question up for you. I was careful to keep the main premise of your question intact but please do advise if you feel this has changed the intent of your question.

Comment: Not really, the rules work the other way around: There is one country you should apply for any given itinerary. What are you planning to do?

Answer (score 1):

The rules are that you should apply to the country where:

1. You will be spending the majority of your time OR
2. The country where the majority of your activity for which you are applying will take place.

If you are spending an equal amount of time in all countries, then you should apply to the first country that you will enter the Schengen zone in.

From my personal experience - some airlines do not allow you to board except to the destination of your Schengen visa country *especially if this is the first time you are traveling on that visa*.

There is no "minimum" amount of time, but the maximum that you can spend in the **entire Schengen zone** depends on the kind of visa you receive.